# Loading required scripts into jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm developing a plugin that makes use of two other plugins.  I was planning on using .getScript() to load the other two scripts, but I'm wondering how best to do this.  Specifically, if the call is async, how can I guarantee that the scripts are loaded before the plugin is initialized?  Would it be smarter to make the calls not async?  (Is that possible? )

Code:

```
(function($){

    // Is this the right place?
    $.getScript('plugin1.js', function() {});
    $.getScript('plugin2.js', function() {});

    // Plugin stuff:
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

        return this.each(function() {

        // Dependent plugins better be loaded by this point!


        }); // End of this.each(...)
    };  // End of plugin
})(jQuery); // End of closure
```

Thanks-

Answer (score 2):

The `$.getScript();` method is basically a wrapper for the `$.ajax();` method. This means it should be hooked into the jQuery Deferred object.

Try this:

```
var loading = $.getScript('myScript.js');

$.when( loading ).then(function() {

    // Start your plugin code here.

});
```

Multiple Actions

```
var script_1 = $.getScript('myScript.js');
var script_2 = $.getScript('myScript2.js');

$.when( script_1, script_2 ).then(function() {

    // Start your plugin code here.

});
```

Comment: @Seth- deffered object looks money- hadn't run into it before.  Can you show me how you would chain multiple scripts?

Comment: @Yarin - I updated the above example to show you how to do multiple deferred's. You can pass as many objects as you need to track.

Answer (score 1):

getScript isn't really a great decision when you have scripts you know you're going to need -- just make sure you include both plugins as `<script>` elements above your own.

But you *could* do:

```
(function($){
  var plugin1Loaded = false;
  var plugin2Loaded = false;

  $.getScript('plugin1.js', function() {plugin1Loaded = true;});
  $.getScript('plugin2.js', function() {plugin2Loaded = true;});

  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    if (plugin1Loaded && plugin2Loaded) {
      ...
    }
  };  // End of plugin
})(jQuery); // End of closure
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of a page calling the plugin before the dependent scripts are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing this, but why not:

```
$.getScript('plugin1.js', function() {
  $.getScript('plugin2.js', function() {
    (function($){

    // Plugin stuff:
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

        return this.each(function() {

        // Dependent plugins better be loaded by this point!


        }); // End of this.each(...)
    };  // End of plugin
    })(jQuery); // End of closure 
  });
});
```

**Update**: Regarding asynchronicity, you should consider whether you don't mind keeping your users waiting at least until both these files are fetched.

Comment: @sombe- Bu what happens if my page tries calling the plugin before the dependencies have loaded- the plugin will not have been initialized..

Comment: @Yarin see the edit. In that case, for example if you have code that needs to fire when the page loads, you'll need to fetch them synchronously.

Comment: Regarding your update- They'll have to wait anyway, as the plugin won't work without them?

Comment: @Yarin they won't wait if you fetch the dependencies asynchronously, and if you don't need whatever use your plugin gives when the page loads (for example, a plugin that handles form submission, assuming it takes time to fill out).